# How do I submit an ERC?

Tags: eip

I think I have a good idea for how to implement a token contract. How do I submit an ERC describing the protocol/API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood it, you raise an [EIP issue](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues), and give it the [ERC label](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/labels/ERC).

You then describe the specification of your standard in the main body of the issue.

Here are the examples for [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/20), and [ERC-223](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/223), their numbers being the EIP issue number.